# Retrieving child's Information from Firebase back to android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Android Studio and Firebase itself. I understand that in order to get the child's data from its unique ID, I might need to use a Data Snapshot method. For example, I need to retrieve the `name` from Firebase database back to android studio application. How do I implement it in this case? Help would be much appreciated!

```
{
  "0Zs7aiWplRRJ5IJ5pazuUOxIdqz2" : {

    "name" : "yeo",
    "pos" : "intern",
    "team" : "nwrs"
  },
  "kaLCjJFoGETWCWH42kNkc90b5Ku1" : {

    "2016" : {
      "9" : {
    "25" : {
      ".priority" : 0.0,
      "AM" : "",
      "OT" : "",
      "OVN" : "",
      "PM" : "",
      "TPT" : ""
    }
      },
      "10" : {
    "1" : {
      ".priority" : 0.0,
      "AM" : "zxc11",
      "OT" : "12",
      "OVN" : "33",
      "PM" : "222",
      "TPT" : "54"
    },
    "26" : {
      "AM" : "aa",
      "OVN" : "gg",
      "PM" : "ccc",
      "TPT" : ""
    },
    "29" : {
      ".priority" : 0.0,
      "AM" : "dd",
      "OVN" : "aa",
      "PM" : "ss",
      "TPT" : "2fd"
    }
      }
    },
    "name" : "Jing Yang",
    "pos" : "Intern",
    "team" : "NWRS"
  }
}
```

Below is my current code

```
    root.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
            Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

            while (i.hasNext()){
                set.add(((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getKey());

            }
            names.clear();
            names.addAll(set);

            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that `root` refers to the root of your database. In that case your `onDataChange` will get a snapshot of the entire data at that location. You can loop over them and get the properties of each child in turn with:

```
root.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            //set.add(childSnapshot.getKey());
            set.add(childSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class));
        }
        names.clear();
        names.addAll(set);

        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But I highly recommend that you create a Java class that represents the items in your list. In your case that can be as simple as:

```
public class Item {
    public string name;
    public string pos;
    public string team;
}
```

Then you can read the items with:

```
root.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Item child = childSnapshot.getValue(Item.class);
            set.add(item.name);
        }
        names.clear();
        names.addAll(set);

        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: If i were to get nested child in 2016 which consist of month do i type it like this?

Comment: set.add(childSnapshot.child("year").child("month").getValue(String.class));